# Why does this Keyboard Input freeze the screen?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I press any of the following keys, the object that I want to move, moves one square and then freeze. When I release the key, the screen unfreeze, and the object moved a lot.
**Why is this happenning? How can I solve this please?**
I am using WPF:

```
private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Key == Key.W)
            {
                playerService.move(Player.id, PlayerService.Direction.UP);
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.S)
            {
                playerService.move(Player.id, PlayerService.Direction.DOWN);
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.A)
            {
                playerService.move(Player.id, PlayerService.Direction.LEFT);
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.D)
            {
                playerService.move(Player.id, PlayerService.Direction.RIGHT);
            }
}
```

**Edit: I am using the following event to draw. How can I control this consedering that I'm blocking the UI Thread?**

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(Draw);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are blocking in the UI thread. I know this is .NET but reference my other answer to a similar problem in Java.

[Skipping over Java KeyEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589538/skipping-over-java-keyevents/4589954#4589954)

**Update**

I would suggest looking into this project and determining how they are handing key events.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/GrandPrix.aspx

It's a racing game written using WPF.

Comment: oh, thank you. But I don't know how to control this. Since I am using CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(Draw); to draw.

Comment: I will see that project. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that project help me how to do. Thank you. This is the asnwer.